# Android : To upload an image using AsyncHttp POST

Tags: java, android, image-uploading, asyncfileupload, loopj

I am having a camera intent activity , I am trying to POST an image selected by the user , to the server. But every time it is giving me Java SSL Socket Exception .
 Below is the method which i have tried to implement for uploading the image to the server .

```
private void postImage(String url) {
        Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
        File file = new File(getFilePath());
        MimeTypeMap map = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getName());
        String mime_type = map.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
        MultipartEntity form = new MultipartEntity();
        form.addPart("files[]", new FileBody(file, mime_type, "UTF-8"));
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.post(context, url, form, mime_type, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject jsonObject1) {
                // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    try {
                        String url = jsonObject1.getString("imageUrl");
                        String blobkey = jsonObject1.getString("blobKey");
                        Log.d(TAG, "IMAGE URL : " + url + " \n BlobKey : " + blobkey + " ");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable e, JSONObject jsonObject1) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Status Code : " + statusCode);
            }

            @Override
            public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
                // called when request is retried
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you add your stack trace?

Comment: Check whether your server is signed with appropriate SSL certificate, it's the issue of SSL certificate installed at your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AsyncHttpClient` supports uploading files. But you should use it like this:

```
RequestParams params= new RequestParams();
//params.put("file", new File(filePath));
params.put("file", new File(filePath), contentType);
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
//client.post(url, params, listener);
client.put(url, params, listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have explained how to upload video here below, Same can be used to upload image.

You can try [HttpClient jar](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) download the latest HttpClient jar, add it to your project, and upload the video using the following method:

```
private void uploadVideo(String videoPath) throws ParseException, IOException {

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(YOUR_URL);

FileBody filebodyVideo = new FileBody(new File(videoPath));
StringBody title = new StringBody("Filename: " + videoPath);
StringBody description = new StringBody("This is a video of the agent");
StringBody code = new StringBody(realtorCodeStr);

MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
reqEntity.addPart("videoFile", filebodyVideo);
reqEntity.addPart("title", title);
reqEntity.addPart("description", description);
reqEntity.addPart("code", code);
httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

// DEBUG
System.out.println( "executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine( ) );
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute( httppost );
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity( );

// DEBUG
System.out.println( response.getStatusLine( ) );
if (resEntity != null) {
System.out.println( EntityUtils.toString( resEntity ) );
} // end if

if (resEntity != null) {
resEntity.consumeContent( );
} // end if

 httpclient.getConnectionManager( ).shutdown( );
} // end of uploadVideo( )
```